# Getting NaN with stopwatch

Tags: java, nan, stopwatch

When using stopwatch and using getAverageTime, I am always getting NaN as the result. Am I doing anything wrong? My code is below.

```
    final StopWatch sw = new StopWatch(true);
    sw.start();
    method1(array);
    sw.stop();
    double AverageTime = sw.getAverageTime();
    System.out.print(" Method 1, time = "+AverageTime+" \n");

    sw.reset();

    sw.start();
    method2(array);
    sw.stop();
    AverageTime = sw.getAverageTime();
    System.out.print(" Method 2, time = "+AverageTime+" \n");

    sw.reset();

    sw.start();
    method3(array);
    sw.stop();
    AverageTime = sw.getAverageTime();
    System.out.print(" Method 3, time = "+AverageTime+" \n");
```

Comment: Which `Stopwatch` implementation are you using? Your question is incomplete.

Comment: I am using stopwatch.jar

Comment: WHICH stopwatch.jar?  There are several.

Comment: Oh! I was not aware of this. This is the JAR file that we were provided with by our professor.

Comment: We cannot know what `sw.getAverageTime();` returns when there is only one time.  Hopefully it just returns the time, but it is conceivable it has a bug or is defined to do something different.  A basic requirement when using any jar file is the API documentation.  Did it come with Javadoc?

Comment: No supporting documetns were provided.

Comment: Do you have the source code?   Are you using the method as intended?  Average implies you're running a method more than one time and collecting the average of many executions.   The code is probably not designed to time something that happens so fast there is 0 elapsed time.

Comment: You should demand Javadoc (and preferably source code) for any library that is provided to you.  As a professional I would demand documentation. If I were forced to use an undocumented jar I would inform the client that the time spent reverse-engineering the jar would be billed as an addition to any existing negotiated price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `NaN` by dividing `0.0` by `0.0`.

The code you have show us does no division, but I surmise that the division is happening in your `getAverageTime()` method.  That is where you should look for the bug in your code.

If this `Stopwatch.jar` file is a 3rd-party library, then you need to check the API documentation.  We can't do that for you because you haven't told us what it is / where you got it from.  (The package name for the `StopWatch` class would be a clue ... bu you don't even give us that.)

---

> This is the JAR file that we were provided with by our professor.

Well I suggest that you ask your professor for the API documentation!

Or ask your professor if there is a bug in the code in the JAR file.

Comment: getAvergaeTime() is a function specified in the StopWatch.jar file which I am importing and using

Comment: The funny part is that, I have used the same jar file even earlier and in the earlier implementation it works just fine ( I just rechecked) but in this implementation its giving NaN

Comment: That's easy to explain.  You are probably using it incorrectly ... now.

Comment: I used it in the same manner. First I used `final StopWatch sw = new StopWatch(true);` Then `sw.start();` **then the code** `sw.stop();` **and then** `getAverageTime();`

Comment: So?   Maybe that is incorrect for >>this<< version of the JAR file.

Comment: I actually thought the same, but we were explicitly asked to use that same approach to get the average run time

Comment: What do the javadocs in the API say is the intended use of the method?

Comment: "Average" run time means you run it several times and average the result.  An average makes no sense for only a single execution.   A method to calculate the average makes no sense without telling it how many times you're running the loop to average.   Something is missing in this entire thing.

Comment: We were not given any supoprting documents.

Comment: Whatever.  If you can't show me the source code or API documentation for the StopWatch class, I can't help you further.

Comment: @DanielWiddis That makes sense to me now. But .. Okay this is what the prblem asks for:  **The program should print -on separate lines- the (average) running time in seconds for each method, as shown in the sample output. Print the actual running times of your methods in place of the xxxx shown in this sample.**

Comment: Using a method without any documentation is a recipe for disaster.  Ask your professor what the method is supposed to do and how it can calculate an AVERAGE of only a single run, or how to tell it you're doing multiple runs.

Comment: Make a bug report to your professor, stating "Stopwatch returns NaN when the time interval is too short.  You probably have a division by zero error in your code."

Comment: You may have more success on a slower computer.

Comment: It makes sense ! I got it. I was doing average time of just 1 run.. I changed it to a loop of 100 and I get results.. Thanks guys

Comment: Actually, I suspect that you were really telling it to give you the average of ZERO runs.  An average of one run wouldn't involve dividing by zero ... but an average of zero runs would!